# how is this model spec working in the discource test suite

Tags: rspec, fabrication-gem

I am looking through the discourse source code here https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/spec/models/invite_spec.rb and see code like this:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Invite do

  it { should belong_to :user }
  it { should have_many :topic_invites }
  it { should belong_to :invited_by }
  it { should have_many :topics }
  it { should validate_presence_of :email }
  it { should validate_presence_of :invited_by_id }
```

I'm unfamiliar with where they are getting a value for `it`. It seems like they have an implicit object here but I don't see where they are creating it - should this be in a before hook?. They are using Fabricator instead of FactoryGirl - can somebody tell me how these are passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implicit subject of `Invite`. This is an RSpec feature:

> The first argument to the outermost example group block is
>   made available to each example as an implicit subject of
>   that example.

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/subject/implicit-subject